# Push segue from a view controller to itself doesn't animate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a board game app that I'm programming which involves a player asking the same question to the other players in a clockwise direction. Since the question is the same for all players, after one player answers the question I want another instance of the same view controller (and its views) to be presented again (with some minor changes in the views to reflect the fact that a different player is being asked the same question).

So here's the problem: When I programmatically try to push the new view controller of type "PlayerAnswerToSuggestionVC" from the first instance of "PlayerAnswerToSuggestionVC" view controller with the following code, there is no animation:

```
        PlayerAnswerToSuggestionVC *patsvc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayerAnswerVC"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:patsvc animated:YES];
```

The new view controller does appear but there is no animation of the transition despite the fact that I am declaring that I do want animation in the "pushViewController:animated:" method. Same thing happens when I try to use a storyboard segue from a UIButton of the first view controller to instantiate a view controller of the same type. The new view controller appears, but without any push transition animation.

I realize that this may be an intended feature and that oftentimes one may not want an animation when going from one view controller to another of the same type. But in my case I do want a visual push transition in order to reflect the fact that the game question is now being directed at a different player. Any ideas on a simple way to implement an animated push transition from an instance of one view controller to another view controller of the same type?

*Additional info discovered: After playing around with the app some more, I have to amend some of my comments above. It appears that the push transition doesn't animate but later in the game the same push transition in another instance of the same view controller class DOES animate. I still have no idea why the push transition doesn't animate the first time time it is attempted, though. Still looking for a pattern to try to understand what is going on...

Comment: you use at the same time other animantion or try to load data with a dispatch?

Comment: No, I'm not using any animations in this part of the program and not doing anything with any other threads. The view controller itself is very simple, which makes me suspect that the observed behavior is simply an intended feature of the frameworks.